# How to find the LDA decision boundary in sci-kit learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to draw the decision boundary obtain with the sci-kit learn LDA classifier.

I understand that you can transform your multivariate data using the `transform` method to project the data onto the first component line (two classes case). How do I obtain the value on the first component that acts as classification pivot? This is, the value that serves as the decision boundary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LDA performs PCA or PCA like operation on $Cov_{between}/Cov_{within}$. The classification pivots are just the first n-1 eigenvectors of $Cov_{between}/Cov_{within}$.

The eigenmatrix is stored in lda.scalings_, so the first component is the first vector of lda.scalings_. It is the decision boundary for 2-class case, but not for the multi-class case